# advanced query combining or and gte and lt in pymongo

Tags: pymongo

How can it implement this in pymongo?

```
number == 100 or (number >=10000 and number < 10100)?
```

currently, I am doing it with

```
*condition['number'] = {'$gte':input_number * 100, '$lt':(input_number + 1) * 100}*
```

and then query with the condition.

But I don't know how to add "number == 100". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
condition['$where'] = '(this.number + "").substr(0, 3) == "%d"' % input_number
```

All I learnt from this is, you can do the query with where and the content for where is a javascript function or something.
But please note that this stupid method is quite slow.